# Can I use "symbol" and "use" tags to preserve the aspect ratio of text in an SVG that has preserveAspectRatio="none"?

Tags: svg

I have an inline SVG image.  I want it to fill the available space, so I set the preserveAspectRatio attribute to "none".  It represents a user selection, so the user coordinates can vary, but are typically quite large.  The user coordinates are important, so I define them in the viewBox so that features are rendered at the "right" relative locations.

I need to put text labels at specific locations on this image, but I've always avoided preserveAspectRatio "none" because glyphs are deformed by the non-preserved aspect ratio. In this case I really need to make it work.

I thought that maybe I could create a symbol for each label on a different SVG that has a default preserveAspectRatio of "xMidYMid meet", and then reference those symbols on my image at the required user coordinates.

It looks like this:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
   <symbol id="label" width="225" height="50" viewBox="0 0 225 50">
      <text text-anchor="middle">Label Text</text>
   </symbol>
</svg>
<svg id="user_selection" width="100%" height="100%"
   viewBox="${rtVB['min-x']} ${rtVB['min-y']} ${rtVB.width} ${rtVB.height}"
   preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <!-- lots elided -->
   <use x="${xloc}" y="${yloc}" href="#label" class="labels" width="225" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

The viewBox width is typically between 1,000 and 10,000.  The height is typically between 100 and 3,000. The result is either complete absence of a label, or a miniscule dot on the screen.  If I get a dot, select it and right click I can see that 1 or sometimes 2 characters from the label have been rendered.
I tried looking at the MDN definition of the 'symbol' and 'use' elements, but I wasn't able to see how to use them to get the desired result.

I thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Why not express the width and height of the use element as some percentage of ${rtVB.width}  (and etc.height)?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your suggestion.  The problem is that the viewBox defines the coordinates in "user space", not screen space.  The presence of preserveAspectRatio="none" distorts the glyphs because screen space isn't in the space proportions to user space.

Comment: The way that I wrote the question emphasises the scale issue, which you addressed in your comment, but I'm looking for the ideal solution that hits the scale issue and the proportions issue.